# How to add dynamically more properties to Json response from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an object which I return wrapped in Json from the controller to the client.

```
return Json(result); //result is DataSourceResult
```

I would like to add some more properties inside this Json response.

How can I do so?

I tried using Json property Data and also casting the DataSourceResult to object and trying to expand it, but whatever I have doesn't look like a good solution.

Comment: Show controller action code & what properties you want to add. You can return anonymous object

Comment: `return Json(new{result=result, someprop="1234"});` ???

Comment: Oh, stupid me, I was looking how to expand the result object, when there was a much easier and better solution. Monday morning is usually a tough time to think :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `anonymous object` like

```
return Json(new {
    result = result,
    myProperty1 = value1,
    myProperty2 = value2
});
```